# Slick element not fully showing after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, slick.js

I am using the slick slider library. On page load, my slider wrapper is set to `display: none`. When I click my trigger click button, it then shows the slider, but the first slide doesn't show. Then when the second slide shows, the height isn't correct.

I have read through articles that share my issue, such as this one:

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/158

Here is the library:

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick

I have tried initializing the slider and then adding `visibility: visible` to it, but that does not seem to work.

Does anyone see or know what I have to add to get the first slide to fully show after being triggered?

[Here is a fiddle which shows the issue I am having.](https://jsfiddle.net/ndzf7gx6/1/)

```js
$('#trigger').on('click', function() {
 $('#pg-preview-wrap').show();
});
$('#calendar-select').on('init', function() {
  $('#calendar-select').css("visibility", "visible");
  $('.slick-initialized').css("visibility", "visible");
});
$('#calendar-select').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 7000,
  speed: 800,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

```css
#pg-preview-wrap {
  display: none;
}

#calendar-select {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 70px auto;
  background: #CCC;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: auto;
}

.no-fouc {
  display: none;
}

.slick-initialized {
  visibility: visible;
}

.slick-slide img.checkmark-img {
  display: none;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-slide img.pg-preview-img {
  display: block;
}

.calendar-option img {
  margin: 20px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.calendar-option-push {
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.calendar-option cite {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin: auto;
  color: #303030;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  display: block;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 120px 120px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: -130px;
  background-image: url("images/arrow-back.png");
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:active,
.slick-prev:focus {
  background-image: url("images/arrow-back.png");
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:active,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:active,
.slick-next:focus {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 120px 120px;
}

.slick-next {
  right: -130px;
  background-image: url("images/arrow-forward.png");
}

.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:active,
.slick-next:focus {
  background-image: url("images/arrow-forward.png");
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.slick-dots {
  margin: 15px 0 20px 0;
}

.white-back {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<button id="trigger">Trigger</button>
<div id="pg-preview-wrap">
  <div id="calendar-select">
    <div class="calendar-option">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="flag-option" class="package-check-toggle">
          <img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/static.graphemica.com/glyphs/i500s/000/009/448/original/25AE-500x500.png?1275323708' alt='American Flag' class='pg-preview-img'>
          <p class="calendar-option-push"></p>
          <cite>A</cite>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="option-check" id='flag-option'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-option">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="nickel-option" class="package-check-toggle">
          <img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/static.graphemica.com/glyphs/i500s/000/009/448/original/25AE-500x500.png?1275323708' alt='Brushed Nickel & Black' class='pg-preview-img'>
          <p class="calendar-option-push"></p>
          <cite>B</cite>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="option-check" id='nickel-option'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-option">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="gold-option" class="package-check-toggle">
          <img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/static.graphemica.com/glyphs/i500s/000/009/448/original/25AE-500x500.png?1275323708' alt='Gold & Black' class='pg-preview-img'>
          <p class="calendar-option-push"></p>
          <cite>C</cite>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="option-check" id='gold-option'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In general .. maybe you need to wrap slick inside the trigger click event or refresh it

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Well, in my actual code, I `fadeIn` the wrapper if a value == x. I did it this way to just demonstrate, but it has the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not a straight forward solution to your problem, you could destroy and reinitialize the slider after it's visible.

```js
var options = {
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 7000,
  speed: 800,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  adaptiveHeight: true
}
$('#trigger').on('click', function() {
 $('#pg-preview-wrap').show();
  $('#calendar-select').slick('unslick');
  $('#calendar-select').slick(options);
});
$('#calendar-select').on('init', function() {
  //$('#calendar-select').css("visibility", "visible");
  //$('.slick-initialized').css("visibility", "visible");
});
$('#calendar-select').slick(options);
```

```css
#pg-preview-wrap {
  display: none;
}

#calendar-select {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto 70px auto;
  background: #CCC;
  height: auto;
}

.no-fouc {
  display: none;
}

.slick-initialized {
  visibility: visible;
}

.slick-slide img.checkmark-img {
  display: none;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-slide img.pg-preview-img {
  display: block;
}

.calendar-option img {
  margin: 20px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.calendar-option-push {
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.calendar-option cite {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin: auto;
  color: #303030;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  display: block;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 120px 120px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: -130px;
  background-image: url("images/arrow-back.png");
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:active,
.slick-prev:focus {
  background-image: url("images/arrow-back.png");
}

.slick-prev:hover,
.slick-prev:active,
.slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:active,
.slick-next:focus {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 120px 120px;
}

.slick-next {
  right: -130px;
  background-image: url("images/arrow-forward.png");
}

.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:active,
.slick-next:focus {
  background-image: url("images/arrow-forward.png");
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.slick-dots {
  margin: 15px 0 20px 0;
}

.white-back {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Slick JS</title>
</head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick-theme.css">
<body>
<button id="trigger">Trigger</button>
<div id="pg-preview-wrap">
  <div id="calendar-select">
    <div class="calendar-option">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="flag-option" class="package-check-toggle">
          <img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/static.graphemica.com/glyphs/i500s/000/009/448/original/25AE-500x500.png?1275323708' alt='American Flag' class='pg-preview-img'>
          <p class="calendar-option-push"></p>
          <cite>A</cite>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="option-check" id='flag-option'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-option">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="nickel-option" class="package-check-toggle">
          <img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/static.graphemica.com/glyphs/i500s/000/009/448/original/25AE-500x500.png?1275323708' alt='Brushed Nickel & Black' class='pg-preview-img'>
          <p class="calendar-option-push"></p>
          <cite>B</cite>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="option-check" id='nickel-option'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calendar-option">
      <div class="product-wrap">
        <label for="gold-option" class="package-check-toggle">
          <img src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/static.graphemica.com/glyphs/i500s/000/009/448/original/25AE-500x500.png?1275323708' alt='Gold & Black' class='pg-preview-img'>
          <p class="calendar-option-push"></p>
          <cite>C</cite>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="option-check" id='gold-option'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.0/slick.min.js"></script> 
 
</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't find any `reInit` method, otherwise that could have been used. Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/3fqgwgdq/1/) of the above code.

Comment: I modified the fiddle to show how my example really is. The slider is shown with inputs in an onchange. You will see I commented out your modifications because they break my code to get the checkmark shown over the slides (click on one and you will see what I mean). However, even with the changes, it does not work. https://jsfiddle.net/ndzf7gx6/2/

Comment: Sorry still not understanding the whole thing, do you want to show slider when checked and hide when unchecked ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. My actual code shows/hides the correct slider... I am mainly having the issue of getting the first slide in the slider to show once shown.

Comment: Please check this, https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/pobf76po/5/ I have removed some codes to just focus on the issue you are having, from based on this I think you should be able to resolve the issue in your project.

Comment: Ok, so I tried integrating this with my page's code (I forgot to add the slider for the second input in my last update), so I added this and got the checkmarks working, but it still doesn't work with my integration. I had to change the `#calendar-select` identifier to the id's of the sliders and a couple of other things. Do you see what I am doing wrong in this?? https://jsfiddle.net/ndzf7gx6/4/  ... The checkmark showing is crucial, that is why there is the extra code.

Comment: @asz06 Do you have any ideas why it isn't working for me?

Comment: You are using wrong id inside your if statement. On your code those functions to show slider are not being called. check here https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/ow6s7mb9/

Comment: Which ids? The fiddle you just linked does the same thing mine did?

Comment: Id of checkboxes inside should be `if ($('#cal-2').is(':checked')) ` and `if ($('#cal-1').is(':checked'))` instead of `if ($('#cal-2year').is(':checked')) ` and `if ($('#cal-whiteboard').is(':checked'))` check this updated one https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/ow6s7mb9/2/

Comment: I don't get it. Mine does not load the first slider selected after triggered. It still does the initial issue, however, now when I change from slider to slider, they appear right away.

Comment: It is like it is not registering the unstick first, for the first slider shown. I have this all in a doc.ready too.

Comment: Please check this one https://jsfiddle.net/azs06/ow6s7mb9/3/ , I hope this is what you are looking for. Hide the slider that you want to display and initiate slick on visible slider. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Even with the last update, it still had the same problem. I figured it out though... I added `$(window).trigger('resize');` and now whenever I click on the first slider it displays. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use .slick("slickRemove") to remove all the slides you want to replace, and then .slick("slickAdd") to add the new ones. Small examples is below,

```
` slickSlider: function () { 
        
    $('#claim_slider').slick({
        infinite: true,                  
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows:true                    
       });             
     }
     
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
      $('.ticket-claims a').on('click', function() {       
        $('#claim_slider').slick("slickRemove");
        $('#claim_slider').slick("slickAdd");
      });
    });    
`
```